# How to get max amount of shared memory for current compute capability in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

My GPU GeForce GTX 1050 Ti has compute capability 6.1. According to the [CUDA docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-6-x) it has 96 KB of shared memory per streaming multiprocessor.

How to get this limit from the program?

I tried to call

```
cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&value, cudaDevAttrMaxSharedMemoryPerBlock, device);
```

and it returned the value 49152 = 48 KB, which is two times smaller than what I am expecting. Why this is so and how to get the actual maximum?

Comment: You are not comparing the same thing. Shared memory per block and shared memory per multiprocessor are different

Comment: @talonmies I didn't know that. How to get shared memory per MP then?

Comment: Use cudaDevAttrMaxSharedMemoryPerMultiprocessor not cudaDevAttrMaxSharedMemoryPerBlock

Comment: @talonmies Thanks, this helps! But now I am wondering why such a difference even exists? Why I can't use the whole shared memory of MP inside the single block?